# Android - Using OSMAnd downloaded data in OSMDroid app

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap

I am wondering if there is a way to download a map by OSMAnd and then use it in my own app using OSMDroid. I know the way with MOBAC, but in this case i need to use already downloaded map (.obf file)

Comment: To those voting down: I have already searched for this kind of solution. StackOverflow and docs say generally about using MOBAC for this purpose. It would be okay for me, but it limits the amount of downloadable tiles so i can not really download that amount of data i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. OsmAnd uses its own vector file format (OBF) which isn't supported by osmdroid.

See the osmdroid wiki for a list of [supported offline file formats](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/Offline-Map-Tiles). It currently lists:

- osmdroid's flavor of a sqlite database (recommended)
- osmdroid ZIP
- MBTiles
- GEMF
- GeoPackage (still under development)

You can also take a look at other libraries with vector map support, for example mapsforge.

Comment: Despite being in Beta, GeoPackage is by far the most exciting offline map feature of the OSMDroid APIs: a very useful open portable container format for vector and raster maps like S-57 ENC.